# help verifying my answer for this" premise-conclusion" question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

For each of the premise-conclusion pairs below, give a valid step-by-step argument (proof) along with the name of the inference rule used in each step.

(a) Premise: {¬p ∨ q → r, s ∨ ¬q, ¬t, p → t, ¬p ∧ r → ¬s}, conclusion: ¬q

---

I did this:

1)  $ p → t  $      Premise

2)  $¬t $        Premise

3) $¬p $        Modus Tol.

4)$¬p ∨ q → r$  premise

5) $q → r $     disj. syll. from 3 ,  4

6) $q ∨ ¬ r $      implication law ( don't know if I'm allowed to use that here)

7) $¬ ( q ∨ ¬ r ) $  Don't know the name of this rule. I'm thinking negation?

8) $¬ q ∧ r  $

9)$ ¬ q   $     by simplification.

Comment: I thought I could use the idea that q→r can be replaced by , let's say, c. so then  $¬p∨q→r $ would be $¬p∨c $ where $¬p $ and the former expression could be reduced using disj. syll. . Also 6 to 7, I thought I could just take the "inverse" of that expression, is that not allowed?

Comment: Here are some troubles I found: 5) cannot be derived from 4) via disj. syll as ¬p is already true, and so q→r doesn't have to be true. 6) cannot be derived from 5) as material implication requires that the antecedent, q, be negated (you negated the consequence, r); so, it would actually be ¬q∨r. 7) cannot be derived from 6) as there is no such valid inference rule, as at least in classical logic, a proposition cannot be both true and false (that's a contradiction); you can't have both (q∨¬r) and ¬(q∨¬r). Hope this cleared up where the trouble was or any misconceptions!

Answer (score 2):

$\neg p \vee q \to r\; $ is $\; \big((\neg p) \vee q\big) \to r \;$ and not $(\neg p) \vee (q\to r)\;$.

Operator precedence goes to the disjunction before the implication.

$\begin{array}{lll}
1) & p \to t  & \text{ Premise }
\\
2) &  ¬t & \text{ Premise }
\\
3) &  ¬p  & \text{ Modus Tolens}
\\
4) & ¬p∨q→r  & \text{Premise}
\\
5') & \neg p \vee q & 3, \text{disjunction introduction}
\\
6') & r & 4, 5', \text{modus ponens}
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$

Can you finish from this?

---

PS: You also have the *implication equivalence* incorrect in your original 6; it's the negation of the antecedent disjunct with the consequent, not the antecedent disjunct with the negation of the consequent.

$$\; a\to c \iff \neg a \vee c \;$$

PPS: You don't need implication equivalence to solve this question.  But learn what it is for when you do.

Comment: ah, better correct that I've been using it wrong for days then! and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You misused the ~p to derive "q->r" given that you have ~p and can only derive ~p from that specific disjunction.  I'm not sure what you did in step six either.

Perhaps try:

Premise: p -> t
Premise: ~t

[~p v t], DeMorgan's law, therefore ~p given premise ~t and disjunctive syllogism.

Premise: [~p v (q -> r)],

use negation [~(~p v (q -> r))] and distribute negation for:

[p & ~(q -> r)] and distribute after converting conditional to disjunction to derive:

[~(~q v r)] then [q & ~r].

Thus we have [p, ~p, q, and ~r].

with p proven, we can revisit your fourth premise, derive the conditional and use the ~r derived from my proof with modus tollens to prove ~q.